# Use a simple LED with no digital pins to spare

Tags: arduino-uno, led, pins, digitalwrite

Problem: I've made a circuit consisting of an 8x8 led matrix, which uses all of the digital pins on the Arduino UNO board, and I want to add an LED too it.

I tried looking around the internet but so far, I have not seen any solution on how to use a simple LED with no digital pins to spare.

So I ask, is it possible to connect an LED with no leftover digital pins? I just want to be able to turn the LED on and off.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this:

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=311099.0

Turns out you can use the analog pins of an Arduino UNO using this:

```
pinMode(A1,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(A1,HIGH);
```

You just have to list it as an analog pin. Seems to be working, don't think there are any downsides, as far as I see.

Comment: Yup.  Though make sure you see the [note](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=311099.msg2158977#msg2158977) there by CrossRoads regarding A6 and A7 on SMT based UNO (and other SMT 328P Arduino).

Comment: In a couple days time you'll be able to *accept* your own answer, and probably should assuming someone else doesn't provide another you like better.

Comment: Ok, yeah I'll do that later, unless I get a better answer as you said.